# How to configure amazon S3 bucket for read-only access to host a static website?

Tags: read-only, acl, amazon-s3

I have a very small (static) website hosted on Amazon S3. Yesterday I received the following message, that had this subject line:

> Notification of Amazon S3 buckets configured for public access

And the message had this this content (screenshot):

[image]

> Hello,
>
> We’re writing to notify you that your AWS account XXXXXXX has one or
>   more S3 buckets that allow read or write access from any user on the
>   Internet. By default, S3 buckets allow only the account owner to
>   access the contents of a bucket; however, customers can configure S3
>   buckets to permit public access.
>
> Unless you have a specific reason (such as hosting a public website)
>   for this configuration, we recommend that you update your bucket and
>   restrict public access. Your list of buckets configured to allow
>   access by anyone on the Internet as of August 9, 2019 are:
>
> ACCOUNT_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>
> If you did not intend to provide public access to this bucket then you
>   should take immediate action by enabling S3 Block Public Access [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHaFF.png) on
>   this bucket. This feature is free of charge and it only takes a minute
>   to enable. For step by step instructions on setting up S3 Block Public
>   Access via the S3 management console, see Jeff Barr’s blog [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWAY7.png). Once
>   you’ve locked down your bucket, we recommend checking for past
>   unintended access to your bucket per the instructions below on
>   analyzing logs.
>
> For more information on S3 Block Public Access, check out the video
>   tutorial on Amazon S3 Block Public Access [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIezG.png). For AWS's definition of
>   "Public Access," please see The Meaning of "Public” [4].

I logged in to my Amazon S3 account and tried to find a way to set up my files for the read-only access. Again, all it has to do is to allow anyone to download. That is it. (As I was obviously not aware of anyone being able to modify my files when I set it up. Allowing this by default would be kinda silly, don't you think?)

I was able to find these controls:

[image]

but I honestly got a raging headache trying to understand how to do that.

Can someone please explain how can I set up my files for read-only access?

---

EDIT: To reply to the answer below, the bucket policy is already set to this:

[image]

Comment: The ambiguous targeting of this email is unfortunate.  It says *"read or write access"* but it literally means "read and/or write access" -- maybe just read, maybe just write, maybe both -- you can't determine from this notification whether the bucket is publicly readable (as you intended) or whether it's publicly writable (as you did not intend).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot man, this is really messed up. Now I totally understand how those S3 buckets get compromised. It's not only so fr*king confusing to set up those permissions, they are also confused themselves who to notify.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Bucket Policy and make sure action as below.

"Action": "s3:GetObject",

Get Object means people can read only.

Comment: I checked, and it's already set to that line (besides some other stuff.) I updated my question with a screenshot. Do I need to remove the rest of it, or what?

Comment: That looks perfect, Its Read-Only Access to public. You don't have to make any changes.

Comment: Thanks. Now (the rhetorical) question is how am I supposed to know at this? How is it in any human logic that "GetObject" would mean "read-only".... or do I need to complete a month-long Amazon-only-security course to know all this. (Just venting.)

Comment: Hello, it is somewhat difficult to understand initially if you don't know JSON policies. Here are some of the reference you can read to understand how it works. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html